# Post validation failed: title: Path `title` is required.in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm receiving the error `` ValidatorError: Path `title` is required `` and my data is not being saved in the database.

What's causing this?

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

const Postschema= new mongoose.Schema({

    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    status:{
        type:String
    },
    description:{
        type:String
    },
    cdate:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now()
    }
});

var Post=module.exports=mongoose.model('Post',Postschema);

router.post('/posts/create',(req,res)=>{
    var post=new Post({
        title:req.body.title,
    })
    post.save(function (err,data){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        console.log(data);
        req.flash('success-message','post successfully created')
        res.redirect('/admin/posts')
    })
})
```

Comment: Fixed up the code formatting, and reworded the user's question. It wasn't clear what the problem they're having was. Now, it's clear that the code supplied is giving a validation error, and an answerer can explain why this means the data's not being inserted into the database.

Comment: please show us how you are triggering your Express route.

Comment: @ahmed I would console log out `req.body.title` when you post and see if anything comes true, I suspect the field is either `null` or `undefined` which means it didn't pass the mongo validation of `required` which you put in place in the `schema`.

Answer (score -2):

The error could be that you haven't configured the express middleware to allow parsing of JSON data in your index/app.js file

// Something like this
app.use(express.json())

Comment: You are basing this on information that is not provided

Comment: Express.js is not mentioned in the question